# How to reopen browser from ChromeDriver after driver.Close?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I currently have a chromedriver initialized. 
This contains the "console" and the actual "chrome browser" windows.

I want to call the chromedriver.Close() method to only close the "browser" window and then reopen it while the application is running. 
I do this because I already have my console in hidden mode, so I want the same for the browserwindow when I'm not using it.

All this without having to Dispose the chromedriver and having to initialize it.

```cs
var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, new ChromeOptions());

//closing browser windows
driver.Close();

//reopen browser window, without reinitializing driver
driver.Open(); //<--Need something that does something like this.
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

**EDIT:**

After the answer of @Guy I implemented this. Which initializes the driver when it's null and when there is no tab open:

```
        if (driver == null)
        {
            var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, new ChromeOptions());
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                var driverUrl = driver.Url;
            }
            catch
            {
                var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
                driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, new ChromeOptions());
            }
        }
```

Comment: driver.Get("") will opens

Comment: I tried it but apparently the driver.Get("") method doesn't exist. @SeniorPomidor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was the last opened window `driver.Close()` will cause the loss of the `driver` instance. You have to reinitialize it

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, new ChromeOptions());
```