# Invoking chromedriver after driver.quit not working?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to invoke Chromedriver after quitting it in my Python script:

```
#set driver options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.binary_location='/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=chrome_options)


#Set base url 
base_url = 'https://www.example.com&page='


events = []
eventContainerBucket = []

for i in range(1,40):

    #cycle through pages in range
    driver.get(base_url + str(i))
    pageURL = base_url + str(i)

    #do some stuff............

driver.quit()


# Want to re-open Chromedriver here to scrape a new URL

#set driver options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.binary_location='/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=chrome_options)


#Set base url 
base_url = 'https://www.example2.com&page='
  
events = []
eventContainerBucket = []

for i in range(1,40):

    #cycle through pages in range
    driver.get(base_url + str(i))
    pageURL = base_url + str(i)
```

The first part of script runs fine and driver closes, but it fails to initialize the driver again on the second URL scrape (`driver.get` is failing). It gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 462, in <module>
    driver.get(base_url + str(i))
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I am not sure about python. But why are you not calling driver = new ChromeDriver() in re-open block? when you call quit() instance will be closed so you need to create new instance again.

Comment: This is not a valid Python code: `new ChromeDriver()`. There is not such a keyword in Python. The right way is `driver = ChromeDriver()`.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`driver.quit()` causes the loss of the `driver` instance.
In order to use `driver` again f.e. by `driver.get` command you will have to have to reinitialize it with

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49131593/how-to-reopen-browser-from-chromedriver-after-driver-close) for reference.